# How to know programatically the error logIn in Mongo Realm?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, realm

I got this to login, the problem is that there is no way to know the reason why failed, I need to show info to the UI or know what type of issue I'm facing. Doc doesn't say anything about errors.

```
try {
  const user = await realmApp.logIn(credentials);
  console.log('signed in', user);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

It print out:

```
Error: Request failed (POST https://stitch.mongodb.com/api/client/v2.0/app/xxxx/auth/providers/local-userpass/login): invalid username/password (status 401)
    at Function.fromRequestAndResponse (bundle.dom.es.js:2696)
    at async Fetcher.fetch (bundle.dom.es.js:2864)
    at async Fetcher.fetchJSON (bundle.dom.es.js:2881)
    at async Authenticator.authenticate (bundle.dom.es.js:2592)
    at async App.logIn (bundle.dom.es.js:3073)
    at async handleSignIn (SignIn.js:37)
```

Programmatically I'm expecting an object with error_code to be able to react to different situations like wrong password/username or email confirmation pending for example.

I also tried not to use async, but it gives same output...

```
  const handleSignIn = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    const credentials = Realm.Credentials.emailPassword(email, password);
    realmApp.logIn(credentials)
      .then(user => console.log(user))
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
    setLoading(false);
  };
```

Also tried the exceptions props e.message and e.name:

e.message:

```
Request failed (POST https://stitch.mongodb.com/api/client/v2.0/app/xxx/auth/providers/local-userpass/login): invalid username/password (status 401)
```

e.name

```
Error
```

Comment: Getting the actual error codes is a bit of a challenge - wish they were laid out more clearly in the documentation. The Swift auth error codes can be obtained from the githib open source code for [RLMSyncAuthError](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/b61081f0d48f57384ef6572eda717524e5baf93e/Realm/RLMSyncUtil.h). Perhaps this link to the [javascript error codes](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/cd88b00c7c97b6b5dd6c8e4825c1cea87d329c28/realm/realm-library/src/objectServer/java/io/realm/mongodb/ErrorCode.java) will provide some direction

Comment: hi @Jay, as a reference is ok, but still have no mechanism to be able to get the current error code in an exception on web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a small CodeSandbox demonstrating how to get the individual properties from the error object:
https://codesandbox.io/s/realm-web-error-codes-2oei2?file=/src/App.tsx

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import { getApp, Credentials, MongoDBRealmError } from "realm-web";

const app = getApp("realmjstestapp-jjhtf");

export default function App() {
  const [error, setError] = useState<MongoDBRealmError | null>(null);
  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    const invalidCredentials = Credentials.jwt("whatever");
    app.logIn(invalidCredentials).then(() => {
      console.log("That was unexpected ...");
    }, setError);
  }, [setError]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Realm Web Error codes</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Make an error!</button>
      {error ? (
        <dl>
          <dt>Combined error message:</dt>
          <dd>{error.message}</dd>
          <dt>Error message:</dt>
          <dd>{error.error}</dd>
          <dt>URL fetched:</dt>
          <dd>{error.url}</dd>
          <dt>Method used when fetching:</dt>
          <dd>{error.method}</dd>
          <dt>Error code:</dt>
          <dd>{error.errorCode}</dd>
          <dt>Status code:</dt>
          <dd>{error.statusCode}</dd>
          <dt>Status text:</dt>
          <dd>{error.statusText}</dd>
        </dl>
      ) : (
        <h2>Click above ..</h2>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27845249)

Comment: @NicoHaase I included the code from the Sandbox in my answer 

Comment: Please also add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Comment: @kraenhansen that is great, im really grateful, i could not find that in the mongo realm doc and i think it should be added. ill open one question more with a realm token bug that im facing in case you want to follow. thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

All of the javascript error codes are wrapped up in an enum called ErrorCodes and they can be found in the [Error Code git](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/cd88b00c7c97b6b5dd6c8e4825c1cea87d329c28/realm/realm-library/src/objectServer/java/io/realm/mongodb/ErrorCode.java)

They are also documented in the [RealmError](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/exceptions/RealmError.html#RealmError-java.lang.String-) class, which Extends the [Error](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/mongodb/ErrorCode.html) class (e) so you can compare it against the available errors

That also gives access to the serialized ErrorCode

My javascript is rusty but can't you do something like this?

```
try {
  do something with realm
} catch (RealmError e) {
  if (e.getMessage().contains("Permission denied")) {
      do something because of the error
  } else {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

or use `e.equals` with the Enums, `e.description` for other info etc

Comment: Hi jay, in JavaScripts we have .name and .message it return a string like the one I posted in the question. I could definitely do contains or regular expressions on an humanised string but that's not a developer way. And I'm sure mongo team does API libs better than that. One interesting thing is that in the failed http post (internally made by signIn menthod) there is a JSON payload with error_code but apparently it's inaccessible from the exception.

Comment: @jjalonso I was not suggesting using RegEx at all - that was just an example option. Please take a look a the `RealmError` which as mentioned, extends the error with a lot more functions to get info about the actual error. e.g. you're not limited to .name and .message. You would then leverage the defined Enums to manage the actual error.

Answer (score -1):

see if this works

```
realmApp.login(credentials).then(data=>{
user = data ; 
 }).error(err=>{console.log(err)})
}
```

make sure to remove async from the function

Comment: Just tried with no success, same error on same way. Ill update the question with that.